# Apache 70007 and 70014 errors

Tags: apache-httpd, amazon-ec2, timeout

I have a service where mobile phones send a big hash of data to our server which are sitting on AWS behind the ELB. 
Once in a while we receive 70007 and 70014 errors in the apache error logs, the requests shows on apache access.log but not in rails logs. I'm trying to figure out what these errors are. 
Our Theory right now is the phone gets disconnected and it happens before the send us the requests so it never hit the rails server.

Errors are the following:

```
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: End of file found (70014)
```

From all the googleing I've done, This is what I've got:

70014: end of file error, which makes total sense according to our theory.

70007: Time out. I put %D on apache log format and I get the time is between 10-90 seconds. Our Apache Timeout setting is 300 seconds. Also a lot of the requests takes longer than 10 seconds and they don't time out.
I also thought it could be TCP timeout, but after investigating realized the TCP timeout is et to 7200 seconds; so that's not it either.

Any idea what this could be? where else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

This question over on serverfault covers the issue, titled: [Apache Proxy TimeOut](https://serverfault.com/questions/272083/apache-proxy-timeout). You have 2 choices:

1. Turn up the logging level

   ```
   LogLevel DEBUG
   ```

   The logging level can be targetted to specific modules too:

   ```
   LogLevel INFO proxy_module:trace5
   ```
2. Increase the Proxy timeout between Apache and the Rails app

   ```
   ProxyPass /boom/ga https://super-load1-ga.test.com connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
   ```

#### References

- [Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 - Log Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

Comment: Thanks @Slm. I turned on the debug but didn't get any more useful info. The issue is I don't get any backtrace. and We are not using proxies. If you think of anything else let me know.